# How to keep iOS app page saved in background and stop the app resetting?

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy

I have an iOS app that displays text data for end users who fly aircraft. After some time with the app in the background, when the app is re-visited, it seems to start the app completely from new again as though it had been completely closed and restarted.

The iOS device that the app runs on is often times in "airplane mode" as well so maybe this is the cause?

The app users will be using multiple apps so can't keep mine constantly open. I need the app to retain the page it was left on along with the data that the user needed.

I have built the app UI using Kivy and am using Kivy's `JsonStore` to save the data. So now I think there is something I need to setup in my `info.plist` to keep the app alive and on the same screen.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Unfortunately a suspended app can be terminated by the system at any time. You need to store sufficient state so that you can restore the state of the app when the user reopens it.

Comment: I can store the displayed data on screen. The problem is that, the whole app starts again from the launch screen and then lands on the home screen which is not where the stored data is displayed. Is there no way to keep the app state 'frozen' until it is re-visited? Thank you.

Comment: Handle on_pause and on_resume, switch to the correct screen in on_resume https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.on_pause

Comment: No, there s no way to prevent your app from being terminated. Here is the link to the native iOS documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have similar apps made by large companies that hang onto the data and screen much longer than mine. Is there any way to maybe just make mine last longer in the background? Or just simply not possible?